# value containing encoded accents in NSString

Tags: ios

I have a string in my Redis DB containing encoded chars with accents:

```
hum... probl\xc3\xa0me :(
```

This is string is correctly read from DB (using node-redis)

```
hum... problème :(
```

But when it is sent to client (iOS app), utf8 encoding appears.

**UPDATE**

After some hours of struggle, I figure this out.
The retrieval from DB is ok, then the transport to the client leads to those encoded chars to be added. On client side I then correct the values , [based on this SOP answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913499/utf8-character-decoding-in-objective-c)

Comment: how do you obtain your `NSString` ?

Comment: @vince I read it from a redis DB where it is saved as "hum... probl\xc3\xa0me"

Comment: I meant how do you end up with that string, no way for you to get the value in db ?

Comment: @vince. I have a process that write the string "hum... problème" in db. When I check the DB, I can see it was saved as "hum... probl\xc3\xa0me". So when I get this string back to my NSString I have the "hum... probl\U00c3\U00a8me"

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099349/using-objective-c-cocoa-to-unescape-unicode-characters-ie-u1234