# How to encode some text correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, utf-8, nsstring

I have some text formatting issues that I need to solve. I have some strange characters displaying from the NSString below

the original string:

```
NSString *descriptionStringPreFormatted = [item objectForKey:@"title"];
```

the formatted string:

```
    NSString *descriptionLabelStringUTF8 = [descriptionStringPreFormatted stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"descriptionStringPreFormatted is %@", descriptionStringPreFormatted);
    NSLog(@"descriptionLabelStringUTF8 is %@", descriptionLabelStringUTF8);
```

here's the output which is the same whether I use the UTF8 encoding or not.

the output:

```
2013-01-05 16:44:51.807 descriptionStringPreFormatted is Â£144.99... 

2013-01-05 16:44:51.810 descriptionLabelStringUTF8 is Â£144.99...
```

Comment: what do you expect the string to be? Also I believe NSString will store string data as utf8 internally by default

Comment: some of the strings are displaying as: "Â£144.99..." instead of"£144.99..." note the "Â" infront of the £ symbol. The source I'm getting the string from displays as "£144.99..." so I'm not sure what's going on

Comment: How are you creating the string?

Comment: I found the answer here:

[stackoverflow link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913499/utf8-character-decoding-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are receiving dictionary "item" from web services. So try to decode that response string from webservice with NSUTF8StringEncoding.
    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
here "responseData" is raw data coming from web services.

Comment: thanks for the response. What if I wanted to use stringWithContentsOfURL: instead of initWithData in that example? I'm currently getting the data via a URL in JSON format