# Showing wrong character for an unicode value in iOS

Tags: ios

I am now working with an iOS app that handle unicode characters, but it seems there is some problem with translating unicode hex value (and int value too) to character.

For example, I want to get character 'đ' which has Unicode value of c491, but after this code:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\uc491"];
```

The value of str is not 'đ' but '쓉' (a Korean word) instead.

I also used:

```
int c = 50321; // 50321 is int value of 'đ'
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithCharacters: (unichar *)&c length:1];
```

But the results of two above pieces of code are the same.

I can't understand what is problem here, please help!

Comment: `'\u0111'` is the code for `'đ'`. You probably confuse about the encoding.

Comment: @nhahtdh: This is correct answer, I would like to see this as an answer.

Comment: That cast from `int` to `unichar` looks dodgy too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The short answer

To specify `đ`, you can specify it in the following ways (**untested**):

```
@"đ"
@"\u0111"
@"\U00000111"
[NSString stringWithUTF8String: "\u0111"]
[NSString stringWithUTF8String: "\xc4\x91"]
```

Note that the last 2 lines uses C string literal instead of Objective-C string object literal construct `@"..."`.

As a short explanation, `\u0111` is the Unicode escape sequence for `đ`, where `U+0111` is the code point for the character `đ`.

The last example shows how you would specify the UTF-8 encoding of `đ` (which is `c4 91`) in a C string literal, then convert the bytes in UTF-8 encoding into proper characters.

The examples above are adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913499/utf8-character-decoding-in-objective-c#4913599) and [this blog post](http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/07/objective-c-tuesdays-unicode-string.html). The blog also covers the tricky situation with characters beyond [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29) (Plane 0) in Unicode.

#### Unicode escape sequences (Universal character names in C99)

According to [this blog](http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/07/objective-c-tuesdays-unicode-string.html)<sup>1</sup>:

> Unicode escape sequences were added to the C language in the TC2 amendment to C99, and to the Objective-C language (for NSString literals) with Mac OS X 10.5.

Page 65 of [C99 TC2 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) shows that `\unnnn` or `\Unnnnnnnn` where `nnnn` or `nnnnnnnn` are "short-identifier as defined by ISO/IEC 10646 standard", it roughly means *hexadecimal code point*. Note that:

> A universal character name shall not specify a character whose short identifier is less than 00A0 other than 0024 (`$`), 0040 (`@`), or 0060 (`` ` ``), nor one in the range D800 through DFFF inclusive.

#### Character set vs. Character encoding

It seems that you are confused between code point `U+0111` and UTF-8 encoding `c4 91` (representation of the character as byte). UTF-8 encoding is one of the encoding for Unicode character set, and code point is a number assigned to a character in a character set. [This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) explains quite clearly the difference in meaning.

> A **coded character set** (CCS) specifies how to represent a repertoire of characters using a number of (typically non-negative) integer values called code points. [...]
>
> A **character encoding form** (CEF) specifies the conversion of a coded character set's integer codes into a set of limited-size integer code values that facilitate storage in a system that represents numbers in binary form using a fixed number of bits [...]

There are other encoding, such as UTF-16 and UTF-32, which may give different byte representation of the character on disk, but since UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 are all encoding for Unicode character set, the code point for the same character is the same between all 3 encoding.

**Footnote**

<sup>1</sup>: I think the blog is correct, but if anyone can find official documentation from Apple on this point, it would be better.

Comment: I get the result from this site: [link](http://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=%C4%91&.submit=%EC%A0%9C%EC%B6%9C).


C491 (hex) = 50321 (dec) as you can see in any conversion tool.

So I need to not use UTF-8 encoding but HTML encoding?