# How to decode an NSString containing UTF8 symbol?

Tags: nsstring, utf8-decode

I got an `NSString`, named `aString`, which contains UTF8 symbol:

```
NSLog(@"aString: %@", aString);

Console => aString: \U00e6\U00b8\U00ac\U00e8\U00a9\U00a6\U00e6\U00a8\U0099
```

How can I decode this `NSString`? I'v tried lots of method, but they didn't work.

Comment: which methods you tried ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF8 character decoding in Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913499/utf8-character-decoding-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

Try [NSString stringWithUTF8String:yourstring]

Comment: The string is an NSString already, not a C string. So your approach dose not work. :(