# Displaying special characters in a UILabel

Tags: objective-c, string, unicode, escaping

I have a string which contains a mix of normal text and special characters. When setting the label text with this string the character codes are being displayed rather than the actual character. I was wondering is there any support for special characters or if there is a way to decode the values?

I have tried **stringWithCString** but haven't had any luck with it.

Setting:

```
self.stringLabel.text = myNSString
```

Result:

```
Hello world!

Ã¨Ã©&ecirc;&euml;ÄÄÄ

&yuml;

&ucirc;&uuml;&ugrave;&uacute;Å«
```

Anyone else come across a similar issue?

Comment: Where do you get the string from, what does it actually look like, what is your current code?

Comment: @luk2302 Just updated the question

Comment: and where do you get the string from?

Comment: @luk2302 The string comes back from an API call

Comment: Have you tried something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913499/utf8-character-decoding-in-objective-c ?

Comment: Thats one of the posts I looked at before but got **[NSString stringWithCString:encoding:]: NULL cString**